android studio emulator apps don't see internet but browser does
Using Android Studio Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2 and am running an emualtor via the following command
emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-snapshot-load -avd Pixel_6_API_34
Problem is while the web browser (Default Chrome) sees the internet no issues any app I want to use just refuses to.
It's widely frustrating, any advice?
Maps Working in Browser
But not working in Map App
I've checked No Proxy is set in the emualtor
Also set cellular meter status to temporarily not metered.

Two things that helped me in the past: use different emulator, preferrably with google apis. Check if no harddrive/emulator space shortage.

Have you installed a user certificate for network interception? If web browser works but apps not this is often caused by the installed user root CA cert which is not trusted by regular apps, only Chrome trusts it.

did you add internet permissions?

Adding a user certificate works for the default google apps, thanks for the suggestion, but still fails on the local app I want to test :( I'll reach out to our developers and see if there are other security constraints built into the app itself.

I think the issue may be I see a display of "No Internet Connection" on the screen but can clearly access the internet via a browser and google apps but other apps don't even try, is there a setting I'm missing.
